# Smooch SDK - websocket disconnected in android

Tags: android, smooch

I am getting this error while receiving message from web end to android app:

```
socket disconnected
12-23 16:43:53.435 31934-31934/io.smooch.demoapp E/WebSocketClient: WebSocket Error!
12-23 16:43:53.435 31934-31934/io.smooch.demoapp E/WebSocketClient: java.io.EOFException
12-23 16:43:53.435 31934-31934/io.smooch.demoapp E/WebSocketClient: at java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:77)
12-23 16:43:53.435 31934-31934/io.smooch.demoapp E/WebSocketClient: at com.saulpower.fayeclient.d.a(Unknown Source)
12-23 16:43:53.435 31934-31934/io.smooch.demoapp E/WebSocketClient: at com.saulpower.fayeclient.f.run(Unknown Source)
12-23 16:43:53.435 31934-31934/io.smooch.demoapp E/WebSocketClient: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
12-23 16:43:53.436 31934-32043/io.smooch.demoapp I/WebSocketClient: socket closed
```

and

```
12-23 17:12:05.224 26644-26644/io.smooch.demoapp E/WebSocketClient: org.apache.http.HttpException: Received no reply from server.
    12-23 17:12:05.224 26644-26644/io.smooch.demoapp E/WebSocketClient: at com.saulpower.fayeclient.f.run(Unknown Source)
    12-23 17:12:05.224 26644-26644/io.smooch.demoapp E/WebSocketClient: at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
    12-23 17:12:05.225 26644-26709/io.smooch.demoapp I/WebSocketClient: socket closed
```

I have made SDK initialized with : `Smooch.init(this, "4sxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");`

and starting activity of `ConversationActivity`.When i am sending messages from app to web no problem comes out, but when web message delivers to app this error comes. Kindly help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Errors like this occur when the web socket closes due to things like the phone going to sleep, etc.

It shouldn't affect the application in any negative way.